# How can I turn initial value of chaos system to key for encryption algorithm?

Tags: matlab, encryption

I used chaos system for encryption with `(1.00001,3.26,22)` as initial value. I want to use these numbers as key.

**Questions:**

- Should I turn my number to `(0100001 0326000 2200000)` (normalizing) and turn them to binary? or turn them *separately* to binary`(1.00001)(3.26)(22)`?
- Is there any function in matlab to convert double to binary like (str2bin)?

Comment: Have you looked at 
["typecast"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html)?

Comment: The conversion function to binary is (confusingly) called `dec2bin`. Other than that, your question is really not sufficiently detailed in order to give an answer.

Comment: but dec2bin is not working for double. dec2bin(2.33)=10